# Mock HTTP Client that is called twice in the same function - Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I was trying to mock Java `HttpClient` using Mockito.

Mockito-core: `v2.15.0`,
Mockito-junit-jupiter: `v2.23.0`

My code looks something like this

```
class Someclass {
    public String funcA(String s) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri1);
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            // some logic
        }
        catch (Exception err) System.out.println(err);
        
        // executed only if failed on first http client call
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri2);
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            // some logic
        }
        catch (Exception err) System.out.println(err);
    
}
```

I was able to mock the first Http call from `HttpClient` successfully using the below code

```
when(mockedCloseableHttpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(mockedHttpEntity);
when(mockedHttpEntity.getContent()).thenReturn(inputStream);
when(mockedCloseableHttpClient.execute(any(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(mockedCloseableHttpResponse);
```

I was not able to mock the second HttpClient call. Help me fix this mocking problem. Please suggest if any logic needs to be changed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can mock multiple interactions by chaining `.thenReturn()`:

```java
when(mockedCloseableHttpClient.execute(any(HttpGet.class)))
  .thenReturn(mockedCloseableHttpResponse) // first invocation returns this
  .thenReturn(yourSecondResponse); // second one
```